# Chrome extension: Authenticate with backend without user interaction

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-authentication, android-authenticator

In our Android app we are able to get authentication tokens without any user interaction (for the purpose of knowing that an api call was received from our app, not for the purpose of getting any user info)

We use:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, anyAccount, "audience:server:client_id:" + MY_CLIENT_ID);
```

How can we do something similar to authenticate api-calls from a chrome extension?

UPDATE:
This is how we get authentication w/o user interaction on Android:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Comment: Not much experience with that, but would https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity help?

Comment: @HaibaraAi sadly the APIs there can only return a token after user interaction allowing the extension to access the user's details, I don't need access to the user details, just need an authentication token to authenticate api calls with my backend

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately when calling [getAuthToken](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity), you can pass a flag `('interactive': true)` or `('interactive': false)`

> `('interactive': true)`
>
> - If you invoke the API in interactive mode, the user is shown a sign in and/or approval UI when necessary, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Image from Google Docs.]

> `('interactive': false)`
>
> - If you invoke the API in silent mode, the API will only return a token if it's possible to produce one without showing any UI. This is useful in cases when an app is doing the flow at app startup, for example, or in general in cases where there is no user gesture involved.

---

## NOTE

> The best practice we suggest is to use silent mode when there is no user gesture involved and use interactive mode if there is a user gesture (for example, the user clicked the Sign In button in your app). Note that we do not enforce any gesture requirement.

Comment: Hey @d.datul1990 I'm aware of the interactive:false option, we use it to re-sign users that had already signed in to the extension, however it doesn't seem to return a token if the user never signed into the extension, in Android we can get a token without the user having to do anything.